# Camel use same JMS Component in many routes

Tags: spring-boot, apache-camel, activemq-artemis

I'm trying to configure 3 Camel Routes to use the same JMS Component.

The problem is when I "have" to use the same component in these differents routes.
When I do that, sometimes an error is showed up informing wasn't possible to connect to ActiveMQ is showed up.
Is this happening because concurrency?
If yes, I would like to know if is there possible configure this component at once and use it without this concurrency.

When I define the componenets with different name, it works.
E.g: amq1, amq2 and amq3.

I'm using:

- Apache Camel: **2.21**
- ActiveMQ Artemis: **1.5.6**
- Springboot: **v1.5.16.RELEASE**

The code:
Method to create the JMS Component:

```
  public JmsComponent createComponent() {
    private ActiveMQJMSConnectionFactory connection;
    connection = new ActiveMQJMSConnectionFactory(host, user, password);
    connection.setMinLargeMessageSize(10000000);

    return JmsComponent.jmsComponent(connection);
  }
```

Adding the Component to route:

Route 1:

```
@Component
public class Route1 extends RouteBuilder {

  @Override
  public void configure() throws Exception {

    if (!getContext().getComponentNames().contains("amq")) {
      getContext().addComponent("amq", createComponent());
    }
    from("amq:" + queue)
      .routeId("Route1")
      .to("mock:result");
  }
}
```

Route 2:

```
@Component
public class Route2 extends RouteBuilder {

  @Override
  public void configure() throws Exception {

    if (!getContext().getComponentNames().contains("amq")) {
      getContext().addComponent("amq", createComponent());
    }
    from("amq:" + queue)
      .routeId("Route2")
      .to("mock:result");
  }
}
```

Route 3:

```
@Component
public class Route3 extends RouteBuilder {

  @Override
  public void configure() throws Exception {

    if (!getContext().getComponentNames().contains("amq")) {
      getContext().addComponent("amq", createComponent());
    }

    from("timer:Test?period=2s")
      .routeId("Route3")
      .setBody(simple("test"))
      .to("amq:" + queue);
  }
}
```

AMQ Broker acceptor:

```
      <acceptors>

         <acceptor name="artemis">tcp://0.0.0.0:61616?connectionTtl=60000;needClientAuth=true;supportAdvisory=false;anycastPrefix=jms.queue.;multicastPrefix=jms.topic.;tcpSendBufferSize=1048576;tcpReceiveBufferSize=1048576;protocols=CORE,AMQP,STOMP,HORNETQ,MQTT,OPENWIRE;useEpoll=true;amqpCredits=1000;amqpLowCredits=300</acceptor>

         <acceptor name="amqp">tcp://0.0.0.0:5672?tcpSendBufferSize=1048576;tcpReceiveBufferSize=1048576;protocols=AMQP;useEpoll=true;amqpCredits=1000;amqpLowCredits=300</acceptor>

         <acceptor name="stomp">tcp://0.0.0.0:61613?tcpSendBufferSize=1048576;tcpReceiveBufferSize=1048576;protocols=STOMP;useEpoll=true</acceptor>

         <acceptor name="hornetq">tcp://0.0.0.0:5445?anycastPrefix=jms.queue.;multicastPrefix=jms.topic.;protocols=HORNETQ,STOMP;useEpoll=true</acceptor>

         <acceptor name="mqtt">tcp://0.0.0.0:1883?tcpSendBufferSize=1048576;tcpReceiveBufferSize=1048576;protocols=MQTT;useEpoll=true</acceptor>

      </acceptors>
```

The error:

```
Error processing exchange. Exchange[ID-op20190003-01-valenet-18-wlgfm-1560467581146-0-2]. Caused by: [org.springframework.jms.UncategorizedJmsException - Uncategorized exception occurred during JMS processing; nested exception is javax.jms.JMSException: Failed to create session factory; nested exception is ActiveMQNotConnectedException[errorType=NOT_CONNECTED message=AMQ119007: Cannot connect to server(s). Tried with all available servers.]]
org.springframework.jms.UncategorizedJmsException: Uncategorized exception occurred during JMS processing; nested exception is javax.jms.JMSException: Failed to create session factory; nested exception is ActiveMQNotConnectedException[errorType=NOT_CONNECTED message=AMQ119007: Cannot connect to server(s). Tried with all available servers.]
    at org.springframework.jms.support.JmsUtils.convertJmsAccessException(JmsUtils.java:316)
    at org.springframework.jms.support.JmsAccessor.convertJmsAccessException(JmsAccessor.java:169)
    at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.execute(JmsTemplate.java:487)
    at org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsConfiguration$CamelJmsTemplate.send(JmsConfiguration.java:526)
    at org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsProducer.doSend(JmsProducer.java:440)
    at org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsProducer.processInOnly(JmsProducer.java:394)
    at org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsProducer.process(JmsProducer.java:157)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.SendProcessor.process(SendProcessor.java:148)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:548)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:201)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:201)
    at org.apache.camel.component.direct.DirectBlockingProducer.process(DirectBlockingProducer.java:53)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.SendProcessor.process(SendProcessor.java:148)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:548)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:201)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:138)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:101)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:201)
    at org.apache.camel.component.direct.DirectBlockingProducer.process(DirectBlockingProducer.java:53)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.SendProcessor.process(SendProcessor.java:148)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:548)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:201)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:138)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:101)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:201)
    at org.apache.camel.component.timer.TimerConsumer.sendTimerExchange(TimerConsumer.java:197)
    at org.apache.camel.component.timer.TimerConsumer$1.run(TimerConsumer.java:79)
    at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:555)
    at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)
Caused by: javax.jms.JMSException: Failed to create session factory
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.createConnectionInternal(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:757)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.createConnection(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:265)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.createConnection(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:260)
    at org.springframework.jms.support.JmsAccessor.createConnection(JmsAccessor.java:180)
    at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.execute(JmsTemplate.java:474)
    ... 26 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.activemq.artemis.api.core.ActiveMQNotConnectedException: AMQ119007: Cannot connect to server(s). Tried with all available servers.
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ServerLocatorImpl.createSessionFactory(ServerLocatorImpl.java:784)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.createConnectionInternal(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:755)
... 30 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Sure. Added in the question.

Comment: I wouldn't expect this issue to be related to concurrency since the acceptor is designed to service remote clients concurrently. What URI are you passing to the `ActiveMQJMSConnectionFactory` constructor? Do you see any exceptions in the broker's log? Have you tried this on the latest release of Artemis (i.e. 2.9.0)?

Comment: I pass the follow URL, "tcp://<ip address>:61616". No I didn't see any execeptions in the logs. I tried only with the Artemis 2.6.3 because we are using Red Hat AMQ 7.2 that behinds is a Artemis 2.6.3. I'm trying to change Artemis Client from 1.5.6 (Current version in Fuse) to the same Broker version to verify if keeps with the same behavior.

Comment: So, this works fine if you use it in a single route, but not if you use it in two routes?

Comment: Sorry for late response. Yes, and if I create a component for each route, works as well.

Answer (score 1):

You could create your own CamelContext by extending DefaultCamelContext and create the component there only once.

```
@Component
class YourCamelContext extends DefaultCamelContext {
  @PostConstruct
  private void addStuff() {
    addComponent("amq", createComponent());
...
```

Comment: Tried that but Springboot don't recognize the Context and Routes... Any tips?

Comment: What do you mean, springboot doesn't recognize context and routes? You just posted above in your question some code with context and routes...